# django wont serve media from heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, buckets

okay so am using whitenoise to store my static files, thats not an issue when deploying to heroku that works perfectly well.

So I need to use S3 to serve my media files. I can upload perfectly to the bucket with no issues, from the website interface that is, but when it tries to load the actual images am trying to serve I instantly get a 404, when I check this 404 in the dev console it shows me the debug message and the link, when I visit the link it actually exists.

So my amazon credentials work, so does CORS and bucket policy, even accessing the images through the link that it claims does exist works.

This is also my MEDIA_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'https://%s/' % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
```

and prints out correctly, is it an issue with using whitenoise and boto storage together?

edit:

so now my static files serve perfectly from S3 but not my media. seems to be ignoring my media_root and media_url